Spring Batch Multitenancy
Implement a multitenant Spring Batch Application. Two alternatives:

Global batch job database and multitenant data databases.
Colocated multitenant batch job and data database tables.

I am able to get multitenancy working in a Spring Batch Job by adding a JobExecutionListener that is able to set the tenant and use a TenantRoutingDataSource (AbstractRoutingDataSource) for the data databases itself.
This means that the job and data databases are different. Do we need JTA distributed transaction manager like Atomikos to ensure correctness of transaction boundary?
For the other alternative ie colocate the job and data tables in the same databases. How do we launch such a job without an initialized JobRepository?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.


This means that the job and data databases are different. Do we need JTA distributed transaction manager like Atomikos to ensure correctness of transaction boundary?

Yes, since resources are not colocated, you need a distributed transaction manager.

For the other alternative ie colocate the job and data tables in the same databases. How do we launch such a job without an initialized JobRepository?

I guess by "an initialized JobRepository" you mean creating the tables. The answer is no, you need to create tables before launching the first job. You can do that manually or, if you use spring Boot, instruct Spring Boot to do it for you. Spring Batch will then manage to create the meta-data of the first job launched without any issue.
